# Importing a single letter from Euler cursive font

Tags: fonts, eulervm

Using the standart Computer Modern font how can I redefine the letter "l" (which looks like a 1 "one" ) with a different more curly font but keep the math font otherwise unchanged?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$ Y_m^l $
\end{document}
```

Desired outcome:

[image: curly l]

Ive done lots of research and there is the same question here [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) but my latex knowledge is not sufficient to tackle the code the desired way.

In the User's Guide to AMSFonts Version 2.2d the curly letter "l" is given in Appendix D, page 32 and the font is given as

> Euler cursive (roman) medium weight {eurm10}

In Hartke´s A Survey of Free Math Fonts for LaTeX the letter of interest is also listed in Figure 1, page 4 under the caption

> Fig.1: Computer Modern (using the Blue Sky and Y&Y Type 1 fonts; no package necessary)

So I wonder whether there is any easy way to switch to that curly "l" letter. Or if the letter has to be separately redefined.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: you have already identified the question that shows the general principle for accessing a single symbol.  the font definitions for euler cursive are in the file `ueur.fd' (in the same directory as `amsfonts.sty` in a tex live installation), and you can get the location of the letter you want from the user's guide you've already looked at.  there isn't a tidy package for the euler cursive, so you'll have to "build your own".

Comment: now that you've edited your question and shown another form of the letter "l", the answer is much simpler -- just use `\ell`, which is part of the basic computer modern complement.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and I havent found that anywhere on the web!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the symbol you are looking for is `\ell`, which is included in the basic computer modern font.

it can be found using [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), as suggested in the question
[How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/579).

detexify found it when i tried, even with my execrable handwriting.